# Read UTF8 and Cp1256 from Xml using DOM Android

Tags: java, android, xml, dom, utf-8

I am using DOM object to read an xml that contains arabic data that all lines are written in UTF-8 except one line that is written in CP1256, while parsing it, it's parsed by default as UTF-8 witch giving "weird letters" for the CP1256 line, how I can tell the DOM parser to parse this line as CP1256, 
Please check the XML: http://alingilalyawmi.org/rss/v2/evangelizo_rss-maa.xml 
When opening it in notepad++ you will realize that data inside   is unreadable until you change the encoding to cp1256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to isolate the one line, you could open an input stream. Then create your own Reader class wrapping two InputStreamReaders, one configured for UTF8 and one configured for CP1256. Then use the UTF8 reader until you reach the CP1256 line, switch to the other reader and back again. Finally, just use your parser on your custom reader class. You'll have to create an InputStream for your parser. From the docs:

```
The SAX parser will use the InputSource object to 
determine how to read XML input. If there is a 
character stream available, the parser will read 
that stream directly, disregarding any text encoding
declaration found in that stream.
```

Comment: Hi I am using this Code:
`code`
try { 
 DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder(); 
 URL u = new URL("http://alingilalyawmi.org/rss/v2/evangelizo_rss-maa.xml");
 Document doc = builder.parse(u.openStream()); 
 NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item"); 
 for(int i=1;i<2;i++) { 
 Element element = (Element)nodes.item(i);
 title = getElementValue(element, "title") + getElementValue(element, "font");
 description= getElementValue(element,"description");
 font=getElementValue(element,"font").toString();
 } 
 }
 catch(Exception ex) { 
  
 } 
 }

Comment: Would you please tell me how to use it per line in the above code?